# Can't find contact in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I'm currently learning react with its documentation, I give myself a challenge and wanted to create a small chat app. I have an understanding some fundamentals and I have a problem with states.

In my code there is a contacts object which holds the information for my contacts. I used a state to contain it and created three buttons with each persons name in it. For the buttons I used a component with two props handleButtonClick and contacts.

```
const contacts = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Taylor', email: 'taylor@mail.com'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Alice', email: 'alice@mail.com'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@mail.com'},
  ];
```

```
const [contactList, setContactList] = useState(contacts);

<ContactList handleButtonClick={handleButtonClick} contacts={contactList} />
```

Inside of the component :

```
export default function ContactList({ handleButtonClick, contacts }) {
  return (
    <div className="contact-buttons">
      {contacts.map((contact) => {
        return (
          <button
            key={contact.id}
            className="personName"
            onClick={handleButtonClick}
            value={contact.id}
          >
            {contact.name}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The thing I want to do is when handleButtonClick executes, it needs to update a state with the id of the person and with that id I want to find the correct person with contactList.find.

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(0);
const contact = contactList.find((c) => c.id === selectedId);

function handleButtonClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setSelectedId(e.target.value);
}
```

And the problem is, for the first person contact starts correctly but it never gets updated. If i am not mistaken when I set the `selectedId` it should trigger a re-render and set contact. What am I missing ?
Thank you !

Comment: Your `id`s in your objects are numbers but `e.target.value` will be a string, so `===` in your find method won't return true since they're different types. Perhaps try with `==` to do a type insensitive check, or convert `e.target.value` when you set your state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the type of what's stored in your `selectedId` state when you update it. Initially, it starts off as a number type, which aligns with the type of your `id` properties in your `contacts` objects. That's why when you call `.find()` initially it can find the `contact` correctly. However, when you update your state to `e.target.value`, you're setting a *string* version of your id to the state (that's because the [`.value` property returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement)). As you are using [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) comparison (`===`) in your `.find()` method, you'll find that your updated `selectedId` won't match any of the objects as the types are different (you're now comparing numeric ids from your objects with your string state id).

You have a couple of options to fix this. The first is to use [loose equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) comparison (`==`), rather than strict comparison `===`, which doesn't care about if the types are different:

```js
const contact = contactList.find((c) => c.id == selectedId);
```

The `==` can behave a bit unexpectedly in some scenarios, so usually, it's best to stick with `===`. Instead, I'd suggest changing your state updating code to set your state to be a number rather than a string. Here I'm doing that using the [unary plus operator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus), but you can use something like [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) to achieve the same result:

```js
setSelectedId(+e.target.value); // or `Number(e.target.value)`
```

---

Alternatively, you can ditch the `value` prop on the button, and instead pass through the selected contact into the function call like so, this way you avoid having to iterate your `contacts` on each render or when your selected id changes:

```js
<button
  key={contact.id}
  className="personName"
  onClick={() => handleButtonClick(contact)}
>
```

Then your handler and state would set and hold a contact object (if possible):

```js
const [selectedContact, setSelectedContact] = useState(() => contacts[0]);

function handleButtonClick(contact){
  e.preventDefault();
  setSelectedContact(contact);
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement the last part and was unsuccessful, you helped me a lot thank you so much.